# Compile Error: Wants Pointer instead of Object

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the following errors when making Arrays of two obecjts.. Edge and Box.

```
error: conversion from 'const Edge*' to non-scalar type 'Edge' requested.
```

I am hoping to return an array of Edges.

On this header file:

```
class Box
{
private:
    bool playerOwned; 
    bool computerOwned;
    Edge boxEdges[4];
    int openEdges;
    bool full;

public:
    Box();
    Box(int x, int y);
    void setEdges(Edge boxTop, Edge boxBottom, Edge boxLeft, Edge boxRight);
    void addEdgeToBox(Edge edge); //add edge to edgeArray.
    void setPlayerOwned(bool point);
    Edge getBoxEdges() const {return boxEdges;}                ****//Error****
    bool getPlayerOwned() const {return playerOwned;}
    void setComputerOwned(bool point);
    bool getComputerOwned()const {return computerOwned;}
    int getOpenEdges() const {return openEdges;}
    bool isFull()const {return full;}

};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Box box);
```

I get the same error except replace 'Edge' with 'Box' on the following line in a non-header file attempting to create a Box.

```
  Box box = new Box(x+i,y);
```

Comment: That statement asks the impossible. "Box box = <something>" sets the box's *value* to the something. But "new Box" actually creates a 'Box', not a value of a Box. You could do: `Box box=Box(x+i,y);`, or more simply `Box box(x+i,y);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Box box = new Box(x+i,y);  //error
```

One error is right here. You should write this as:

```
Box *box = new Box(x+i,y); //ok
```

It is because when you use `new`, you're allocating memory, and only a pointer can hold a memory, so `box` has to be *pointer* type.

Similarly,

```
Edge getBoxEdges() const {return boxEdges;}  //error
```

should be written as:

```
const Edge* getBoxEdges() const {return boxEdges;}  //ok
```

It is because `boxEdges` is an array, which can decay into pointer type to its first element, and since it is const member function, `boxEdges` will decay into `const Edge*`.

---

By the way, instead of *pointer* in the first case, you use automatic object as:

```
Box box(x+i, y); //ok
```

---

I would suggest you to make the second parameter of `operator<<` a const reference:

```
//std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Box box); //don't use this
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Box const & box); //use this
```

This avoids unnecessary copy!

Comment: I guess I don't understand why I should use a pointer, instead of just use the object?

Comment: @mcudm001, it seems like you're used to Java/C# were the "new" operator is how you create an object. In C++, the "new" operator allocates memory on the heap, and the only way to access it is through a pointer to the memory location. Creating an object on the stack is a different syntax.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what my problem was.  Never learn Java before c++.... Or learn to pay better attention.

Comment: @mcudm001: Java and C# programmers should be more careful when programming in C++. C++ is a different universe with its own set of laws and rules, many of them *look like* same as the rules in Java and C#, but they *actually* aren't.